# Differential Geometry - Gauss Curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, differential

Let $M$ be a compact (without boundary) orientable surface in $\mathbb R^3$. Suppose $M$ is not diffeomorphic to a sphere. Show that there must exists a point $p$ of $M$ at which the Gauss curvature $K$($p$) < 0.

Any help?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** If the genus of your surface is greater than $1$, apply Gauss-Bonnet. If your surface is a torus, note that any compact surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ must have a point of positive curvature and again apply Gauss-Bonnet.

Comment: i wish i understood any of that :/

Comment: @yeezyszn: Well, you do need to know the basic tools before you can solve problems with them... Read up about the theorem and see if you can apply it to get what you want.